# Setup create-react-app with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

**Problem** - I am not able to get any response from postman when hitting localhost:9000. It should give me  a user json back which is in my routes file only for time being. Instead it spits out the following.

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.ce2f0561.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Setup**

Using create-react-app with express to connect.

My folder structure is

--src `React app lives in this`

--server

-- index.js

-- express.js

-- controllers

-- routes

```
-- rs_notes.js
```

**rs_routes.js**

```
'use strict';



  module.exports = function(router){
     const notesController = require('../controllers/cs_notes');

    router.route('/', function(req, res, next) {
        // Comment out this line:
        //res.send('respond with a resource');

        // And insert something like this instead:
        res.json([{
            id: 1,
            username: "samsepi0l"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            username: "D0loresH4ze"
        }]);
    });
    };
```

**express.js**

```
 const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
// Setup logger
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms'));

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));
require('./routes/rs_notes')(router);
// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const app = require('./express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Full project link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35OQMkRo3KcSHlkeXdWVjVjc0U/view?usp=sharing

My questions or doubts are

1. Am I passing the router in a right way. We used to pass app in this
   way prior to express 4 ? So not sure if same structure works here.
2. I am able to load it in browser by hitting localhost:9000 (server is run by node server command as configured)  but not in postman.

Comment: Is this the HTML that is served, or are you seeing this as text? Former would seem ok to me.

Comment: Does it work in the browser?

Comment: Hold on.... I accidently submitted it...let me edit and ask properly

Comment: Not as text but html @idmean

Comment: @Colin yes it does

Comment: I suppose that postman does not support JavaScript on client side and reactjs is a full JavaScript library.

Comment: But I am not yet interacting with react from this. if I do cd into server and hit node index. Server goes up at 9000. At this point it is just a node app. Then too postman returns the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix up this stack by learning the use of Router appropriately and moving some code here and there. But it was still not working for base route i.e when I  simply do router.get('/', ...). Gives the same error message. So I rather reversed the approach of connecting node and react. I published my efforts on medium for the same reason as two separate posts.

https://medium.com/@kushalvmahajan/i-am-about-to-tell-you-a-story-on-how-to-a-node-express-app-connected-to-react-c2fb973accf2